# Unity www class crashes on iOS 64 bit

Tags: ios, web, unity-game-engine, 64-bit

I just built an application for iOS 64 bit using unity 5.1, xcode 6.4`.

I'm calling a Rest API with some headers inside. But the application crashes on this www call.

The crash point is somewhere in `FeedUnityWebStream` which is an assembly file, hence no help from crash point. Crash log has some entries of CFNetwork library.

This API has been working fine on 32 bit build.

Please help

**API Call**

```
string url = "http://gamelootnetwork.com/apis/RestServer.php/";

        WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
        form.AddField("method","imatrixLogin" );
        form.AddField("imatrix_id", strEmail);
        form.AddField("password", strPassword);
        WWW www = new WWW(url, form);
        loading = DashUpUtil.showLoadingIndicator(transform.parent);
        StartCoroutine(WaitForRequest(www));
```

**Crash Log**

```
Incident Identifier: B99794F3-44F8-4569-8B85-4DD43A00A2D0 CrashReporter Key:   01fb558dcc66147392c762d8463e5c11b693f6b5 Hardware Model:      iPad4,4 Process:             lootflyer [4089] Path:        /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/66682A15-3FFA-4C58-8DDB-7D85A800BFBE/lootflyer.app/lootflyer Identifier:          com.gamelootnetwork.lootflyer Version:           
1.1 (1.1) Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native) Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2015-07-14 17:14:17.480 +0500 Launch Time:        2015-07-14 17:13:45.889 +0500 OS Version:          iOS 8.1.2 (12B440) Report Version:      105

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV) Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00000001bb27beb8 Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  main  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread Thread 0 Crashed: 0   libobjc.A.dylib                   0x00000001946cfbd0 objc_msgSend + 16 1   lootflyer                      0x0000000100e9b258 WWW::FeedUnityWebStream(bool) (WWW.cpp:236) 2   CFNetwork                        0x0000000183746e6c
__65-[NSURLConnectionInternal _withConnectionAndDelegate:onlyActive:]_block_invoke + 76 3   CFNetwork                       0x0000000183746dfc
-[NSURLConnectionInternal _withConnectionAndDelegate:onlyActive:] + 204 4   CFNetwork                       0x0000000183746f78
-[NSURLConnectionInternal _withActiveConnectionAndDelegate:] + 56 5   CFNetwork                         0x000000018361b8e0
___ZN27URLConnectionClient_Classic26_delegate_didFinishLoadingEU13block_pointerFvvE_block_invoke + 100 6   CFNetwork                        0x00000001836e453c ___ZN27URLConnectionClient_Classic18_withDelegateAsyncEPKcU13block_pointerFvP16_CFURLConnectionPK33CFURLConnectionClientCurrent_VMaxE_block_invoke_2
+ 100 7   CFNetwork                         0x0000000183607b50 RunloopBlockContext::_invoke_block(void const*, void*) + 72 8   CoreFoundation                   0x0000000183b84aa8 CFArrayApplyFunction
+ 64 9   CFNetwork                      0x00000001836079fc RunloopBlockContext::perform() + 132 10  CFNetwork                       0x00000001836078b0 MultiplexerSource::perform() + 308 11  CFNetwork     0x00000001836076dc MultiplexerSource::_perform(void*) + 64 12  CoreFoundation                   0x0000000183c5a9e8
__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 20 13  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183c59c8c
__CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 260 14  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183c57d3c __CFRunLoopRun + 708 15  CoreFoundation              0x0000000183b850a0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 392 16  GraphicsServices      0x000000018cceb5a0 GSEventRunModal + 164 17  UIKit                      0x00000001884ba3bc UIApplicationMain + 1484 18  lootflyer               0x0000000100086254 main (main.mm:40) 19  libdyld.dylib                  0x0000000194d2aa04 start + 0

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager Thread 1: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000194e28c94 kevent64 + 8 1   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000194d1097c
_dispatch_mgr_invoke + 272 2   libdispatch.dylib                0x0000000194d033b0 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 48

Thread 2: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x0000000194e43c78
__workq_kernreturn + 8 1   libsystem_pthread.dylib          0x0000000194edd390 _pthread_wqthread + 988 2   libsystem_pthread.dylib          0x0000000194edcfa4 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 3: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x0000000194e43c78
__workq_kernreturn + 8 1   libsystem_pthread.dylib          0x0000000194edd390 _pthread_wqthread + 988 2   libsystem_pthread.dylib          0x0000000194edcfa4 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 4 name:  GC Finalizer Thread 4: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib       0x0000000194e43078 __psynch_cvwait + 8 1   libsystem_pthread.dylib      0x0000000194edefe0 _pthread_cond_wait + 620 2   lootflyer               0x00000001016a396c il2cpp::os::posix::PosixWaitObject::Wait(unsigned int, bool) (PosixWaitObject.cpp:128) 3   lootflyer                         0x0000000101683644 FinalizerThread(void*) (gc.cpp:35) 4   lootflyer     0x000000010169f1bc il2cpp::os::Thread::RunWrapper(void*) (Thread.cpp:83) 5   lootflyer                      0x00000001016a7170 il2cpp::os::ThreadImpl::ThreadStartWrapper(void*) (ThreadImpl.cpp:91) 6   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000194edfe7c _pthread_body + 160 7   libsystem_pthread.dylib          0x0000000194edfdd8
_pthread_start + 156 8   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000194edcfac thread_start + 0

Thread 5 name:  BatchDeleteObjects Thread 5: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x0000000194e28eb8 semaphore_wait_trap
+ 8 1   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000194d0ea4c _dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow + 252 2   lootflyer                        0x0000000101014264 ThreadedStreamBuffer::HandleReadOverflow(unsigned int&, unsigned int&) (ThreadedStreamBuffer.cpp:291) 3   lootflyer          0x0000000100f6c534 BatchDeleteStep2Threaded(void*) (BatchDeleteObjects.cpp:93) 4   lootflyer                        0x00000001010138b4 Thread::RunThreadWrapper(void*) (Thread.cpp:40) 5  libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x0000000194edfe7c _pthread_body + 160 6   libsystem_pthread.dylib          0x0000000194edfdd8 _pthread_start + 156 7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194edcfac thread_start
+ 0

Thread 6 name:  AsyncReadManager Thread 6: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib   0x0000000194e28eb8 semaphore_wait_trap + 8 1   libdispatch.dylib        0x0000000194d0ea4c _dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow + 252 2   lootflyer    0x000000010102766c AsyncReadManagerThreaded::ThreadEntry() (AsyncReadManagerThreaded.cpp:85) 3   lootflyer                      0x000000010102746c AsyncReadManagerThreaded::StaticThreadEntry(void*) (AsyncReadManagerThreaded.cpp:53) 4   lootflyer                       0x00000001010138b4 Thread::RunThreadWrapper(void*) (Thread.cpp:40) 5  libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x0000000194edfe7c _pthread_body + 160 6   libsystem_pthread.dylib          0x0000000194edfdd8 _pthread_start + 156 7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194edcfac thread_start
+ 0

Thread 7 name:  UnityWorker Thread 7: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib        0x0000000194e28eb8 semaphore_wait_trap + 8 1   libdispatch.dylib        0x0000000194d0ea4c _dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow + 252 2   lootflyer    0x00000001010133c8 CappedSemaphore::WaitForSignal() (CappedSemaphore.h:63) 3   lootflyer                        0x0000000101012db8 JobQueue::ProcessJobs(void*, bool*) (JobQueue.cpp:573) 4   lootflyer                         0x00000001010125f8 JobQueue::WorkLoop(void*) (JobQueue.cpp:579) 5   lootflyer                       0x00000001010138b4 Thread::RunThreadWrapper(void*) (Thread.cpp:40) 6   libsystem_pthread.dylib          0x0000000194edfe7c _pthread_body + 160 7   libsystem_pthread.dylib          0x0000000194edfdd8 _pthread_start + 156 8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194edcfac thread_start
+ 0

Thread 8: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x0000000194e28eb8 semaphore_wait_trap + 8 1   lootflyer                        0x000000010160e4f4 algThreadJobQueueThreadFunc + 32 2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194edfe7c _pthread_body + 160 3   libsystem_pthread.dylib          0x0000000194edfdd8 _pthread_start + 156 4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194edcfac thread_start
+ 0

Thread 9 name:  UnitySubstanceThread Thread 9: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib           0x0000000194e28eb8 semaphore_wait_trap
+ 8 1   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000194d0ea4c _dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow + 252 2   lootflyer                        0x0000000100f26efc SubstanceSystem::ThreadMain(void*) (Semaphore.h:22) 3   lootflyer                        0x00000001010138b4 Thread::RunThreadWrapper(void*) (Thread.cpp:40) 4   libsystem_pthread.dylib          0x0000000194edfe7c _pthread_body + 160 5   libsystem_pthread.dylib          0x0000000194edfdd8 _pthread_start + 156 6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194edcfac thread_start
+ 0

Thread 10: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib           0x0000000194e28eb8 semaphore_wait_trap + 8 1   lootflyer                        0x00000001012bea58 FMOD_OS_Semaphore_Wait(FMOD_OS_SEMAPHORE*) + 12 2  lootflyer                         0x00000001012da7bc FMOD::Thread::callback(void*) + 60 3   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x0000000194edfe7c _pthread_body + 160 4   libsystem_pthread.dylib      0x0000000194edfdd8 _pthread_start + 156 5   libsystem_pthread.dylib     0x0000000194edcfac thread_start + 0

Thread 11 name:  AURemoteIO::IOThread Thread 11: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x0000000194e28e7c mach_msg_trap + 8 1  libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000194e28cf4 mach_msg + 68 2   AudioToolbox                   0x00000001832997b8 AURemoteIO::IOThread::Run() + 112 3   AudioToolbox                   0x000000018329cf9c AURemoteIO::IOThread::Entry(void*) + 8 4   AudioToolbox                      0x00000001831bcdd8 CAPThread::Entry(CAPThread*) + 140 5   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x0000000194edfe7c _pthread_body + 160 6   libsystem_pthread.dylib      0x0000000194edfdd8 _pthread_start + 156 7   libsystem_pthread.dylib     0x0000000194edcfac thread_start + 0

Thread 12: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib           0x0000000194e43570
__semwait_signal + 8 1   libsystem_c.dylib              0x0000000194d6592c nanosleep + 212 2   libsystem_c.dylib                0x0000000194d65848 usleep + 64 3   lootflyer                        0x00000001012be5b8 FMOD_OS_Time_Sleep(unsigned int) + 16 4   lootflyer                      0x00000001012da7a8 FMOD::Thread::callback(void*) + 40 5   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x0000000194edfe7c _pthread_body + 160 6   libsystem_pthread.dylib      0x0000000194edfdd8 _pthread_start + 156 7   libsystem_pthread.dylib     0x0000000194edcfac thread_start + 0

Thread 13: 0   libsystem_pthread.dylib          0x0000000194ee3e08 DYLD-STUB$$_platform_memmove + 4 1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194edd4dc _pthread_mutex_lock + 308 2   CoreFoundation         0x0000000183c5a184 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 472 3   CoreFoundation        0x0000000183c580dc __CFRunLoopRun + 1636 4   CoreFoundation             0x0000000183b850a0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 392 5   CoreFoundation        0x0000000183bd71f8 CFRunLoopRun + 108 6   CoreMotion                    0x000000018458298c 0x184540000 + 272780 7   libsystem_pthread.dylib     0x0000000194edfe7c _pthread_body + 160 8   libsystem_pthread.dylib      0x0000000194edfdd8 _pthread_start + 156 9   libsystem_pthread.dylib     0x0000000194edcfac thread_start + 0

Thread 14 name:  UnityPreload Thread 14: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib     0x0000000194e28eb8 semaphore_wait_trap + 8 1   libdispatch.dylib        0x0000000194d0ea4c _dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow + 252 2   lootflyer    0x0000000100f72704 PreloadManager::Run() (Semaphore.h:22) 3   lootflyer                         0x0000000100f726b0 PreloadManager::Run(void*) (PreloadManager.cpp:174) 4   lootflyer        0x00000001010138b4 Thread::RunThreadWrapper(void*) (Thread.cpp:40) 5  libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x0000000194edfe7c _pthread_body + 160 6   libsystem_pthread.dylib          0x0000000194edfdd8 _pthread_start + 156 7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194edcfac thread_start
+ 0

Thread 15 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader Thread 15: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000194e28e7c mach_msg_trap + 8 1  libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000194e28cf4 mach_msg + 68 2   CoreFoundation                 0x0000000183c59ecc
__CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 196 3   CoreFoundation                 0x0000000183c57e20 __CFRunLoopRun + 936 4   CoreFoundation              0x0000000183b850a0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 392 5   CFNetwork             0x000000018368a4e4 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 436 6   Foundation                       0x0000000184b75c08
__NSThread__main__ + 1068 7   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x0000000194edfe7c _pthread_body + 160 8   libsystem_pthread.dylib      0x0000000194edfdd8 _pthread_start + 156 9   libsystem_pthread.dylib     0x0000000194edcfac thread_start + 0

Thread 16 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private Thread 16: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib           0x0000000194e43498 __select + 8 1   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183c5f8c4 __CFSocketManager + 656 2   libsystem_pthread.dylib          0x0000000194edfe7c
_pthread_body + 160 3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194edfdd8 _pthread_start + 156 4   libsystem_pthread.dylib     0x0000000194edcfac thread_start + 0

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x000000017025f110   x1: 0x0000000188c31a22   x2: 0x0000000100d6c924   x3: 0x0000000000000010
    x4: 0x0000000000000000   x5: 0x0000000000000000   x6: 0x00000001700ce018   x7: 0x0000000000000a80
    x8: 0x0000000101c43000   x9: 0x00000001bb27bea8  x10: 0x0000000135864170  x11: 0x000000150000001f    x12: 0x0000000135864330 x13: 0xbaddaaa9bb27bead  x14: 0x0000000000000000  x15: 0x0000000000000001    x16: 0x00000001946cfbc0  x17: 0x0000000100086f1c x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000134772190    x20: 0x000000016fd7e580  x21: 0x0000000000000001  x22: 0x0000000000000001  x23: 0x0000000188c258a0    x24: 0x0000000170215640  x25: 0x000000016fd7e578  x26: 0x000000019533eb82  x27: 0x000000019534ae0c   x28: 0x0000000000000000  fp: 0x000000016fd7e620   lr: 0x0000000100e9b25c
    sp: 0x000000016fd7e570   pc: 0x00000001946cfbd0 cpsr: 0x20000000

Binary Images: 0x100080000 - 0x101a3ffff lootflyer arm64  <d635920668cb367da501e96792f926bd> /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/66682A15-3FFA-4C58-8DDB-7D85A800BFBE/lootflyer.app/lootflyer 0x107450000 - 0x107537fff AGXMetal arm64  <3a033d413b883c0fa09891bfb237e3fa> /System/Library/Extensions/AGXMetal.bundle/AGXMetal 0x1200fc000 - 0x120123fff dyld arm64  <36eff49275c23d2d815e48af33eea471> /usr/lib/dyld 0x18247c000 - 0x18260ffff AVFoundation arm64  <c9cd60a62cfb3e77be72db6cd3062a09> /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/AVFoundation 0x182610000 - 0x182674fff libAVFAudio.dylib arm64  <017d90360b443ae788ef31cfd73d17f6> /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/libAVFAudio.dylib 0x182678000 - 0x1826b7fff AVKit arm64  <8eb98ea09dfe3b218fd8a71197a85ad2> /System/Library/Frameworks/AVKit.framework/AVKit 0x1826b8000 - 0x1826b8fff Accelerate arm64  <e9ba7838f51634a7b59ed392be50e86f> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate 0x1826d0000
- 0x1828effff vImage arm64  <da44067fc79931c7aef1b7e88bf82a83> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vImage.framework/vImage 0x1828f0000 - 0x182997fff libBLAS.dylib arm64  <e5276e7784ef34a4baca480264978ea0> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib 0x182998000 - 0x182d12fff libLAPACK.dylib arm64  <165b05f9f75736d5ae8f5f39293bd6e7> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib 0x182d14000 - 0x182d29fff libLinearAlgebra.dylib arm64  <5574ec3bd4e537e1b662d38a63aec58b> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLinearAlgebra.dylib 0x182d2c000 - 0x182d94fff libvDSP.dylib arm64  <004f5668574139bc906c5fa4fdced3b1> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib 0x182d98000 - 0x182dbbfff libvMisc.dylib arm64  <5790e7ace143367ea6f2428852be384e> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvMisc.dylib 0x182dbc000 - 0x182dbcfff vecLib arm64  <211d7711a6e93fe8ae6d6b42585cad2d> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib 0x182dc0000 - 0x182deefff Accounts arm64  <2508d336b9893176ad4e1bc67ff04188> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accounts.framework/Accounts 0x182df0000 - 0x182df0fff AdSupport arm64  <977faefc983d3d72ad5e531740e4130a> /System/Library/Frameworks/AdSupport.framework/AdSupport 0x182df4000 - 0x182e76fff AddressBook arm64  <09e2e24ef5e23fb8a62ae209466a64bd> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook 0x182e78000 - 0x182fc8fff AddressBookUI arm64  <e79239b432af33e783296d2a9841578e> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBookUI.framework/AddressBookUI 0x182fcc000 - 0x182fdffff AssetsLibrary arm64  <78cfe4f1af67381fb6941f4b1f25eef9> /System/Library/Frameworks/AssetsLibrary.framework/AssetsLibrary 0x183190000 - 0x18344dfff AudioToolbox arm64  <f0b739a395993b808d66e85e1a6e9f18> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox 0x1835ec000 - 0x1837f7fff CFNetwork arm64  <68adcebf440d30769bd2d67adc7932a2> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork 0x1837f8000 - 0x18388ffff CloudKit arm64  <8f226c83b2793a0db1eefa14d697c04b> /System/Library/Frameworks/CloudKit.framework/CloudKit 0x183890000 - 0x1838f5fff CoreAudio arm64  <10aae62ba1c43dd29bc678fbf0f985ef> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio 0x183918000 - 0x183939fff CoreBluetooth arm64  <9ccc8812db60356ebb123ca9ca36f958> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreBluetooth.framework/CoreBluetooth 0x18393c000 - 0x183b7afff CoreData arm64  <33c0d795a45e35c9affed5cf9d83a8a1> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/CoreData 0x183b7c000 - 0x183ed8fff CoreFoundation arm64  <83a9627362333366a8543e8c2d28166e> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation 0x183edc000 - 0x18403efff CoreGraphics arm64  <783a6b9356ed3b41beba516b483affb1> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics 0x184094000 - 0x184096fff libCGXType.A.dylib arm64  <a23bc017fe0d3c2293a1391fe5ef658b> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCGXType.A.dylib 0x184098000 - 0x1840a3fff libCMSBuiltin.A.dylib arm64  <f691d5f2368d3b7d8668c7cbf6044af7> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCMSBuiltin.A.dylib 0x184298000 - 0x1842b6fff libRIP.A.dylib arm64  <c7960ba6e4183d9cbb673b112b6ba300> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib 0x1842b8000 - 0x1843e5fff CoreImage arm64  <444c44b06f533bad9c1b030edd486b49> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework/CoreImage 0x1843e8000 - 0x184445fff CoreLocation arm64  <d8470e5719473c82a5f089624a04a1e5> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation 0x184480000 - 0x18453efff CoreMedia arm64  <af73ae8152763066a3fc18bcbcdecf94> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia 0x184540000 - 0x18460efff CoreMotion arm64  <b4148dfdca2036e893becf42286d9e09> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMotion.framework/CoreMotion 0x184610000
- 0x184681fff CoreTelephony arm64  <f99cf601387938d3808c32e97a9a30cf> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony 0x184684000 - 0x184786fff CoreText arm64  <128434ae7dda35bf8830f1914999fe3a> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText 0x184788000 - 0x1847a4fff CoreVideo arm64  <402f868dbba63d59a3b2e738982b9d71> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo 0x1847a8000 - 0x1848ccfff EventKit arm64  <15cacaa609e33790a3bc644eb4d92191> /System/Library/Frameworks/EventKit.framework/EventKit 0x184a80000 - 0x184cd4fff Foundation arm64  <fb0544132648377c8d2683d597a3583d> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation 0x184d04000
- 0x184d2dfff GSS arm64  <7b3a88cbb59d33088db0fae35c30b7da> /System/Library/Frameworks/GSS.framework/GSS 0x184d30000 - 0x184d40fff GameController arm64  <d022e54deaa630a19aa960141db9ca6e> /System/Library/Frameworks/GameController.framework/GameController 0x184dec000 - 0x184e58fff IOKit arm64  <1cd3da5151d03be5a0ba0c30c19228ea> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit 0x184e5c000 - 0x1850f6fff ImageIO arm64  <100a3b5e1ea13c89a9771cad8f9508b2> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO 0x1850f8000 - 0x185598fff JavaScriptCore arm64  <8b0fade3317b38358fe56ac5ba61e2f3> /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore 0x185e0c000 - 0x185e12fff MediaAccessibility arm64  <5dc0d8bda3593b9cb00a8703b21953fd> /System/Library/Frameworks/MediaAccessibility.framework/MediaAccessibility 0x185e14000 - 0x18602ffff MediaPlayer arm64  <5c56df4977f33b41bdc6b6aed053f85b> /System/Library/Frameworks/MediaPlayer.framework/MediaPlayer 0x186030000 - 0x18644afff MediaToolbox arm64  <0468767c75bb342cbbefc64bdf948be5> /System/Library/Frameworks/MediaToolbox.framework/MediaToolbox 0x18644c000 - 0x18651ffff MessageUI arm64  <f307aec0262838e1ad1302805c8a025c> /System/Library/Frameworks/MessageUI.framework/MessageUI 0x186520000 - 0x186593fff Metal arm64  <69e3d92ae3ec3375a550022b7ac4a184> /System/Library/Frameworks/Metal.framework/Metal 0x186594000 - 0x186640fff MobileCoreServices arm64  <19505cbb66af328785e293c3b2810b00> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices 0x186764000 - 0x186799fff OpenAL arm64  <1bbe9dd773463d5c93a368ff87097ed4> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenAL.framework/OpenAL 0x1877c4000 - 0x1877cefff OpenGLES arm64  <b707e102e4553f26994bfef0579c9f52> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES 0x1877d4000 - 0x1877d5fff libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib arm64  <7e1f08d7776b37efb6ff01f6486afcde> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib 0x1877d8000 - 0x1877dbfff libCoreFSCache.dylib arm64  <5888d3587c633af2ac7cf57ac15ab5e4> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreFSCache.dylib 0x1877dc000 - 0x1877e0fff libCoreVMClient.dylib arm64  <291806c545fe3219b844a93e2fb682b4> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreVMClient.dylib 0x1877e4000 - 0x1877eefff libGFXShared.dylib arm64  <f5e5cfc1d6673d469f25b3fa77fa995b> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib 0x1877f0000 - 0x18783bfff libGLImage.dylib arm64  <4e284cf07fe23789b94c9f204f7aa52e> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib 0x187d9c000 - 0x187f20fff QuartzCore arm64  <313aba56d17e30d1b68b2fdfda1820f8> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore 0x187f24000
- 0x187f7ffff QuickLook arm64  <ae12a3ed0acf3b6ca816e95d4a894d70> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuickLook.framework/QuickLook 0x1881b4000 - 0x188206fff Security arm64  <823c0a3088543396bef1e351da74c835> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security 0x188208000 - 0x188293fff Social arm64  <928581a049c3306abe816e5113d652ae> /System/Library/Frameworks/Social.framework/Social 0x1883b0000 - 0x1883c8fff StoreKit arm64  <e7adbf448a9839529a876e42b9293a44> /System/Library/Frameworks/StoreKit.framework/StoreKit 0x1883cc000 - 0x18843ffff SystemConfiguration arm64  <cbcb5237ab8637aebf0cb493aaa4af92> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration 0x188444000 - 0x188db8fff UIKit arm64  <31ac3f3fa5153620907fbfbfd1d671b0> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit 0x188dbc000 - 0x188e35fff VideoToolbox arm64  <13a05b41cd0136239ef94de508febe1d> /System/Library/Frameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox 0x188e38000 - 0x189099fff WebKit arm64  <ec363b6f17ba3f068df0b771aa8ddc44> /System/Library/Frameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit 0x18909c000 - 0x1890d5fff iAd arm64  <ead03dc7b6af33949da0e8566de248cd> /System/Library/Frameworks/iAd.framework/iAd 0x189418000 - 0x18941bfff AGXCompilerConnection arm64  <dca7ebb27c1735c299a4ec26e1529213> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AGXCompilerConnection.framework/AGXCompilerConnection 0x189494000 - 0x18949afff AITTarget arm64  <b9bb1c4d7ba1350e98f02f665923e52e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AITTarget.framework/AITTarget 0x1894a0000 - 0x1894adfff AOSNotification arm64  <8b9793a334fa3013803a6cb713053b44> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AOSNotification.framework/AOSNotification 0x189638000 - 0x189690fff AccountsDaemon arm64  <84c862ef63b332eb81b98f5ab414e3f4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccountsDaemon.framework/AccountsDaemon 0x189694000 - 0x1896bafff AccountsUI arm64  <a7d2776eb1ad39d887a5e62c0292e597> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccountsUI.framework/AccountsUI 0x1896bc000 - 0x1896c1fff AggregateDictionary arm64  <2f9120e6400835f08bd7bfd2d4ada020> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary 0x1898c0000 - 0x1898f4fff AirPlaySupport arm64  <6f3dd0a70c643317b21ca301bd142257> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AirPlaySupport.framework/AirPlaySupport 0x189b40000 - 0x189b8afff AppSupport arm64  <f35ee13bec64354d9044e2a5ea519640> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport 0x189b8c000 - 0x189bdffff AppleAccount arm64  <267a2b98738333f099ccb095820590d6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleAccount.framework/AppleAccount 0x189ce8000 - 0x189d30fff AppleJPEG arm64  <8377453201ad3862b7b6182be4ac4342> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleJPEG.framework/AppleJPEG 0x189d44000 - 0x189d58fff ApplePushService arm64  <fc28105486c5380f95f8d52a3a3c2fac> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ApplePushService.framework/ApplePushService 0x189d5c000 - 0x189d65fff AppleSRP arm64  <7a5d169c15b83573a29f1c018c8ecbb8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleSRP.framework/AppleSRP 0x189d78000 - 0x189d83fff AssertionServices arm64  <52d911832bf9382d802961ea9d1614f9> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssertionServices.framework/AssertionServices 0x189d84000 - 0x189d9ffff AssetsLibraryServices arm64  <5db6341939f63eaa86f0c0306e2b59c9> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices 0x189da0000 - 0x189dcafff AssistantServices arm64  <4d30491ebb4f324d8a2d3910f3f5739e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssistantServices.framework/AssistantServices 0x189e04000 - 0x189e08fff BTLEAudioController arm64  <8539b6078e1b3c739d412842418188ed> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BTLEAudioController.framework/BTLEAudioController 0x189e0c000 - 0x189e28fff BackBoardServices arm64  <6ff3989d8caf3130aa41d0019ead5472> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BackBoardServices.framework/BackBoardServices 0x189e30000 - 0x189e6dfff BaseBoard arm64  <62044bafc2293567aec7797b25708b48> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BaseBoard.framework/BaseBoard 0x189e70000 - 0x189e77fff BluetoothManager arm64  <2b1c765aab5a3ba6b6f8ded22ce99d6b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BluetoothManager.framework/BluetoothManager 0x189e78000 - 0x189ea8fff Bom arm64  <2724021b087139bcaa636d640e9b4127> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom 0x189f44000 - 0x189f4cfff CacheDelete arm64  <81d93e7702c3390dbf003caa716dc3fb> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CacheDelete.framework/CacheDelete 0x189fa0000 - 0x189fd0fff CalendarFoundation arm64  <210e5342ce603b9887f0e10131df34a4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CalendarFoundation.framework/CalendarFoundation 0x18a108000 - 0x18a112fff CaptiveNetwork arm64  <8ba9d547383b3a7fba9a31cc361fc06a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CaptiveNetwork.framework/CaptiveNetwork 0x18a114000 - 0x18a25efff Celestial arm64  <24aa1094177c3a5ead8cd4fa3369b83a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Celestial.framework/Celestial 0x18a270000 - 0x18a28bfff CertInfo arm64  <34bb9442ee1633238c1830d4ba2e7103> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CertInfo.framework/CertInfo 0x18a28c000 - 0x18a292fff CertUI arm64  <d540e6a6a1ab3b119b88d31509a2f390> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CertUI.framework/CertUI 0x18a3dc000
- 0x18a400fff ChunkingLibrary arm64  <ef3f4a4cae2d387b874e53eec51b37aa> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ChunkingLibrary.framework/ChunkingLibrary 0x18a834000 - 0x18a8f8fff CloudPhotoLibrary arm64  <a7679e757e94373cb6c1f024e0f3b431> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CloudPhotoLibrary.framework/CloudPhotoLibrary 0x18a958000 - 0x18a95afff CommonAuth arm64  <be739a349719388087584ff4b16e0a0d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CommonAuth.framework/CommonAuth 0x18a95c000 - 0x18a96efff CommonUtilities arm64  <1cb495ce473a3127bb291cc541762fb3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CommonUtilities.framework/CommonUtilities 0x18a970000 - 0x18a974fff CommunicationsFilter arm64  <836ffdf2d1bf38948dc8ce6c2f8179e1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CommunicationsFilter.framework/CommunicationsFilter
```

Comment: please add your crash log along with a dump of the API request, including the headers and request body.  Thanks!

Comment: crash log and api call has been added. log is a bit truncated due to character limit. But I think the relevent part is there

Comment: Thanks for the update.  Would you also be able to get a dump of the request itself to go along with the code, i.e. the actual http request being sent under the hood?  It's possible that there's something in there that would help solve this problem.